# Error on moment when loading javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, momentjs, script-tag

I am rewriting part of my index.html in order to load scripts dynamically. When using script tags it works perfectly. However when i use functions to load dynamically the same script., I get an error on moment.

The error happens in my Application.js where I am using the moment object as such:

```
moment.locale((window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language));
```

The error is as follows: *Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined*

Anything I am missing here? How can I get rid of this error?

Please find below my original and the reworked index.html file.

**LOADING VIA SCRIPT TAG**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=10, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta name="description" content="App">

    <title>App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/dist/resources.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Cmd to build your application -->
    <script id="microloader" data-app="6d7f39b3-ffca-49e6-8d86-147d346be804" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/dist/resources.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**DYNAMICALLY LOADING JAVASCRIPT**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=10, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta name="description" content="App">

    <title>App</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/dist/resources.min.css"> -->

    <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
    <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-137507021-2"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'UA-137507021-2');

        function loadjscssfile(fileName, filePath, fileType) {
         let fileref = document.createElement('script');
            if (fileType == 'css') {
                fileref = document.createElement('link');
                fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
                fileref.setAttribute("href", filePath + fileName); 
                fileref.setAttribute("async", true);
            } 
            if (typeof fileref != "undefined")
            {
              document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
            }
        };
        loadjscssfile("resources.min.css", "resources/dist/", 'css');
    </script>
</head>

<body>

<!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Cmd to build your application -->
    <script id="microloader" data-app="6d7f39b3-ffca-49e6-8d86-147d346be804" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="configuration/WSConstants.js"></script>
    <script src="resources/dist/resources.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

       function loadjscssfile(fileName, filePath, fileType) {

            let fileref = document.createElement('script');        
            if (fileType == 'js' || fileType == 'text/javascript') {
                fileref.onload = function(){
moment.locale((window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language)); //Still getting same error
};
                fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
                fileref.setAttribute("src", filePath + fileName);
                fileref.setAttribute("async", true);
            }

            if (fileType == 'css') {
                fileref = document.createElement('link');
                fileref.onload = function(){};
                fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
                fileref.setAttribute("href", filePath + fileName); 
                fileref.setAttribute("async", true);
            }

            if (typeof fileref != "undefined"){
                document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(fileref);
            }
        };

        loadjscssfile("resources.min.js", "resources/dist/", 'js');
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

***This is the Application.js***
The moment is called in the launch function:

```
var Bundle = {};
Ext.define('App.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

    name: 'App',

  launch: function() {
    moment.locale((window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language));
 }
});
```

As you suggested I put it on the fileref.onload section in the index.html (see code edited above). Still the same problem persists.

Comment: It's possible that you are running moment before the js file is loaded. You need a event listener to check when the dynamically loaded js has completed loading, then you execute your `moment.locale...` code

Comment: @gugateider I added this piece of code. Is this what you mean or sort of? Can you help with an example here pls
```
class Main {
                constructor() {
                this.init();
            }

            init() {
                window.moment = moment;
            }
        }
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            console.log('loaded');
            moment.locale((window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language));
        new Main();
        });
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full source code, it looks like you're trying to use `moment.locale` on document load, that's wrong because moment will be undefined on document load. Once the document loads and then will start loading your moment js, which is where you should execute your code. Maybe somewhere around the line `fileref.onload = function() { ... code goes here }`

Comment: @gugateider code edited above and also put the Application.js code that was previously causing the error.

Comment: Any other help pls?